# Install Additional Printer Drivers (x86) on Vista (x64) - Can't find suitable (x86) ntprint.inf

Tags: windows-vista, drivers, 64-bit, printer

I have a printer connected to my computer that I'd like to share on my home network - shouldn't be a problem.

The computer the printer is connected to is running Vista Ultimate x64. The computers I'm trying to share with are x86 Windows XP Professional and x86 Vista, so I need to install additional (x86) drivers.

[image: Printer sharing]

I checked the box to add x86 printer drivers and then it asked for the location of the drivers. I browsed to the location and clicked OK.

[image: Add additional drivers]

It then prompted "Please provide path to Windows media (x86 processor).

[image: Locate ntprint.inf]

When I click "Browse..." it wants the location of a file named ntprint.inf

It looks like it's asking for a Windows (x86) installation disk. I put one in but I can't seem to find this file on the 32-bit Vista install disk

Where is the proper place to find this file?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to download the drivers from the printer manufacturer website.

Comment: That's what I did - after I select the location of the downloaded driver it then prompts for the location of ntprint.inf.

Comment: It may be that what you've downloaded is a compressed file, can you right click and extract files.  What is the model of the printer?

Comment: It's a Dell Laser 1700. The driver comes as a self-extracting .exe. So, I have extracted the files to choose the correct driver. That part works fine. After I choose the correct driver, it then prompts me for the location of the (x86) ntprint.inf file. It's usually located in C:/Windows/inf/ - but I'm on Vista x64, so I can't use that one.

Comment: Have a look at this file from microsoft it seems to give some hints http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/f/7/af7777e5-7dcd-4800-8a0a-b18336565f5b/pkginstall.doc

Answer (score 1):

jmohr, i too had this issue and just blogged about the the solution.
http://jasonmlee.net/archives/365

Comment: Worked for me, annoying, but doesn't seem like a hack.

Answer (score 0):

i386 is a directory on the Microsoft 2003 installation CD.

Answer (score 0):

I used this solution from http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverprint/thread/59c1d8e4-76f4-415a-9ec1-7046c9d417a2

> To install an x86 additional driver on a Windows Vista x64 host, you first 
>      need a running Vista x86 system. On this x86 system, locate the directory
>      \Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\ntprint.inf_xxxxx

I have a 2008 R2 (x64 by default) host, and found the ntprint.inf folder on a Windows 7 32 bit PC.

you are seeking a folder, not a file.